# Mysterious behavior of Rectangular Marquee Tool in Photoshop CS4 on Snow Leopard

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My selection boundary always snaps to the top left corner of the image boundary.

I have googled about this and found this page below:
http://thedailyreviewer.com/design/view/marquee-tool-always-snaps-to-boundaries-in-cs4-10450278

The symptom is the same, but the solution ( resetting all tools ) doesn't work for me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

[Plus]
I cannot even move the selection boundary. Whenever I let go the left button, the selection boundary goes back to the top left corner.

Comment: Is a CS5 upgrade a possibility for you? CS4 is a Carbon app (essentially an OS9 app running on OSX) while CS5 is Cocoa (native OSX API) and solves a lot of problems.

Comment: @Stan So you implied this should be regarded as a bug, instead of mis-configuration, right?

Comment: Yes. Resetting the config may solve the problem in some instances, but the problem shouldn't occur in the first place.

Comment: Same issue on CS3. Worked fine for a couple of years, now the marquee tool (and the font tool) has the wrong behaviour -- appears to grow in all directions when I click and drag, but when I let go the selection is what you would expect given the mouse movements. I'd rather not have to upgrade to CS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Photoshop CS5. It's OK now.